# Karate Extent Report integrtion

Tags: karate, extentreports

Karate -junit will provide  Reports as BDD. We have new requirement to push this report to Report server KLOV(Extent Reports). Is this possible to with listener's? please let know the documentation.

**Integration Extent Report with Karate frame work.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the documentation here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-info

> within a test (or within the afterScenario function if configured) you
> can access metadata such as the Scenario name

You can add an `afterScenario` "listener" like this:

```
* configure afterScenario = 
"""
function(){
  var info = karate.info; 
  karate.log('after', info.scenarioType + ':', info.scenarioName);
  karate.call('after-scenario.feature', { caller: info.featureFileName });
}
"""
```

Refer to this file for more details [`hooks.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/hooks/hooks.feature)

EDIT: also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54527955/143475

Comment: Thank you Peter .

Comment: Can  i override the KarateReporter inteface and track  details like given ,when,then and steps details-

Comment: @rama no, not what I recommend

Comment: i want to push  the report to  KLOV server(Extent). Is there any way i can achieve it?

Comment: @rama yes. refer answer. karate provides hooks. what you do in them is up to you